# :focus with a link

Tags: html, css

The link that I have works just fine with the focus tag when singular, but I would like to make that link activate a div. It also activates it fine, but the problem is that the focus command doesn't stay active after it's been clicked. Is there a way to get the focus tag remain active after the link has been clicked and the div has been activated without any JQuery or Java in general?

Here's the CSS:

```
a.clicker:link {
height: 449px;
width: 600px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
-o-transition: 3s;
-ms-transition: 3s;
-moz-transition: 3s;
-webkit-transition: 3s;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url('');
background-color: #000;
}
a.clicker:focus {
opacity: 0 !important;
right: -400px !important;
}

.div {
height: 500px;
width: 700px;
border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
position: fixed;
top: 70px;
left: -650px;
opacity: 0;
-o-transition: 3s;
-ms-transition: 3s;
-moz-transition: 3s;
-webkit-transition: 3s;
}
.div:target {
top: 70px;
left: 300px;
opacity: 1;
}
```

And here's the html:

```
<a href="#01" class="clicker"></a>
<div id="01" class="div">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with CSS alone.

Once someone clicks elsewhere, the link is no longer in focus, and thus the rule no longer applies.  If you want to apply a style change permanently on focus, then you need to use javascript/jquery and change css with onFocus or onClick.

For jQuery (I know you specifically asked for without jQuery, but for completeness' sake):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clicker').click(function(event) {
        $(this).css("opacity", "0!important");
        $(this).css("right", "-400px!important");
    });
});
```

Untested, this is an approximation, and probably won't work 100% out of the box.  Note - you must include the jQuery library.